# How can I convert these premises into a logical argument?

Tags: logic, expression

I have the following three premises:

```
P or Q
P => R
Q => R
```

The symbol **=>** represents the *'implies'* operation. I understand that these premises constitute a dilemma, but how can they be combined into one logical expression?

Comment: could you please clarify the source of these premises? Are they all hypothesis or some of them must be proven using others? Or you should use them to solve 4th something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each proposition in the list is true at the same time, there's an implied `and` among them.

```
(P v Q) ^ (P => R) ^ (Q => R)
```

but we know that `(P v Q)` is `True`:

```
True ^ (P => R) ^ (Q => R)
```

and that leaves us with just:

```
(P => R) ^ (Q => R)
```

An implication like `P => R` translates to:

```
~(P ^ ~R)
```

and that can be converted to:

```
(~P v R)
```

using that, we have:

```
(~P v R) ^ (~Q v R)
```

if we factorize we get:

```
(~P ^ ~Q) v R
```

since:

```
(~P ^ ~Q) == ~(P v Q)
```

we have:

```
~(P v Q) v R
```

but we know that `(P v Q)` is `True`:

```
~True v R
```

or:

```
False v R
```

and that leads to the final answer:

```
R
```

Comment: How do we know (P V Q) is True? Besides that, I couldn't have asked for a better answer, thanks!

Comment: @amorimluc In the dilemma you're asserting that every proposition is true. When you solve it, you either get a result, or a contradiction, that proves that all propositions cannot be true at the same time.

Comment: You can also keep (P v Q) till the end. It will be a demonstration with lengthier equations, but the result will be the same because you'll get something like `(P v Q) ^ ~(P v Q) v R`, which is `R`. In the method I used (I don't remember its name), you take the first proposition as given, and then prove if the others hold.

Answer (score 0):

The initial problem presentation is just Or-Elimination in Natural Deduction.  This is a principle of intuitionistic logic, it does not require a classical argument about Boolean Algebra here.

Intuitively, P v Q is like the type of a disjoint sum of either P or Q (like a union type in some programming languages). If you have a way to go from P => R and another to go from Q => R --- in other words functions of that type, respectively --- you can put them together to eliminate the disjunction and get result R in both cases.

This is sometimes presented as a higher-order functional combinator like this:

```
case: P v Q => (P => R) => (Q => R) => R
```

You can actually *define*  P v Q is the logical operator that allows this reasoning for arbitrary R.

Further note that this is one of the key aspects of the Curry-Howard correspondence of logic and programming.

Answer (score -1):

implication A=>B  should be read as "if A is TRUE B CANNOT be FALSE" for boolean algebra it has an equivalent formula: implication  A=>B is (!A || B) .

in your case P=>R ~ !P || R , Q=>R ~ !Q||R  so we have !(P || Q) && R

update: complex expression is usually made by &-ing simple expression. Most likely you should prove some some expression X (let say P == "it is raining", Q == "it is snowing" , R == "I'll take an umbrella". And you should prove something like X == "I'll take an umbrella if it  is raining and snowing")

So you do ((P || Q) && (P=>R) && (Q => R) ) => X. and you should check if it is true for all cases when simple expressions are true. Left part of this is exactly equals P||Q && R

Comment: Why is it not (!Q||R) || (!P||R) ?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I don't understand how you reduced the equation to !(P||Q) && R ?

Comment: The first statement says that `(P||Q)` is `True`, so your final answer is actually `!True&&R`, or `False&&R`, which is always `False`. That answer is wrong. The part where you missed it is was in the factorization, `!(P || Q) && R`, which should have been `!(P || Q) || R`. Edit, and I'll remove the -1.

Comment: how did you factorized (~P v R) ^ (~Q v R) to get (~P ^ ~Q) v R ? (~P v R) ^ (~Q v R) -->  (~P v R)^~Q v (~Q v R)^R --> ~P^~Q v R^~Q v ~Q^R v R^R --> ~P^~Q v R^~Q v ~Q^R v R --> and now using formula A or (A and B) = A --> R !!! or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: ~P^~Q v R^~Q v ~Q^R v R^R --> ~P^~Q v R^~Q v ~Q^R v R  must be read as ~P^~Q v R^~Q v ~P^R v R^R --> ~P^~Q v R^~Q v ~P^R v R

Comment: @mishmashru The factorization is a basic one in logic. It's very easy to prove. If `R` is false, then you get `~P ^ ~Q`. If `R` is true, you get True. Therefore the posibilities are `~P ^ ~Q`, or `R`, which is `(~P ^ ~Q) v R`. You can use a truth table to check it.

Comment: I wrote truth table for F(P,Q,r) = (P || Q) && (P=>R) && (Q => R)

Comment: F(P,Q,R) = 1 for Z = {(0,1,1), (1,0,1), (1,1,1)} but not for (0,0,1) so how it can be ... || R? And the actual equivalent formula for F is PvQ^R. It turns 1 on the same set Z. OR I do not understand initial question at all. One thing I do not understand: why you are saying that P or Q is true? this is just hypothesis which may be either TRUE or FALSE